# MySQL - Error to sum distinct rows

Tags: mysql

I want the sum of the amount for distinct ids

My query is like that

```
SELECT DISTINCT pyId,  paId, (pyCredit) As Credit, pyDate
FROM T20 
INNER JOIN T30 ON T20.paId = T30.ttLien20
      INNER JOIN  T49 ON T30.id30 = T49.tEchLien30
      INNER JOIN  T50 ON T30.id30 = T50.acLien30
     INNER JOIN  T60 ON T49.techId = T60.ecId49 OR T50.acId = T60.ecLien50
     INNER JOIN  T70 ON T60.ecId = T70.pyLien60 
WHERE   pyId IN (42978,44138,44139)
```

With DISTINCT criteria only 3 results:
42978   8606    194.00  2016-11-29
44138   8606    194.00  2016-12-21
44139   8606    6.00    2016-12-21

If I lunch the same query without DISTINCT keyword, 6 rows
42978   8606    194.00  2016-11-29
42978   8606    194.00  2016-11-29
44138   8606    194.00  2016-12-21
44138   8606    194.00  2016-12-21
44139   8606    6.00    2016-12-21
44139   8606    6.00    2016-12-21

I'd like to create a SQL query generator, so I'd to found a solution to generate very simple query code.
My first idea was :

```
SELECT DISTINCT pyId,  paId, SUM(pyCredit) As Credit, pyDate
FROM T20 
INNER JOIN T30 ON T20.paId = T30.ttLien20
      INNER JOIN  T49 ON T30.id30 = T49.tEchLien30
      INNER JOIN  T50 ON T30.id30 = T50.acLien30
     INNER JOIN  T60 ON T49.techId = T60.ecId49 OR T50.acId = T60.ecLien50
     INNER JOIN  T70 ON T60.ecId = T70.pyLien60 
WHERE   pyId IN (42978,44138,44139)
```

But is this case each row is added twice !!! So the global sum is worse.

The result is good even if I do something like that

```
Select SUM(Credit) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT pyId,  paId, (pyCredit) As Credit, pyDate
FROM T20 
INNER JOIN T30 ON T20.paId = T30.ttLien20
      INNER JOIN  T49 ON T30.id30 = T49.tEchLien30
      INNER JOIN  T50 ON T30.id30 = T50.acLien30
     INNER JOIN  T60 ON T49.techId = T60.ecId49 OR T50.acId = T60.ecLien50
     INNER JOIN  T70 ON T60.ecId = T70.pyLien60 
WHERE   pyId IN (42978,44138,44139)) t1
```

But is more diffucult to generalize. So is there a better way to reach my goal ?

Best regards